# Cron on Amazon EC2 centos still executes even after delete

Tags: linux, centos, cron, amazon-ec2

I have a `cron` job in machine 1 that opens/close machine 2 for a few hours.

Now i deleted all `cron` jobs in machine 1, so it wont open/close machine 2.

I have no `cron`s,

To delete all `cron`s in machine 1. I used:

```
sudo crontab -r
```

but for some reason the machine 2 continue to open/close

I even used to check `cron` log on machine 1:

```
sudo cat /var/log/cron
```

I do NOT see the stop/start commands there at the log. So it seems `cron` jobs does NOT open/shut machine 2.

Cron job was a root.

When executing the following commands:

> sudo crontab -l and crontab -l

They give me:
"no crontab for root" and
"no crontab for centos" .

Executing the command:

> sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/

returns **Total 0**

/etc/crontab contains:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```

Doing **ls cron*** inside etc folder shows:

```
cron.deny  crontab

cron.d:
0hourly
cron.daily:
logrotate  man-db.cron
cron.hourly:
0anacron
cron.monthly:
cron.weekly:
```

Previously it was a Root cron job.
I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: Are the cronjobs running as user root? Did you edit `/etc/crontab` ? Have you *added* the cronjobs previously as root? What is `crontab -l` saying? Did you use `at` or `batch` ? What do `sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/*` say ? **Edit your question** to improve it please!

Comment: don't comment but please **edit your question**, also showing `/etc/crontab` file and files under `/etc/cron*`

Comment: Updated question with your questions and results. Do you see something i that could cause the question issue?

Comment: There is not by any chance a copy of machine 1 running with the old cron job still active?

Comment: umm, i have an older Amazon Machine Images (AMI) of that machine , but it should be just an image ..

Comment: You need to be sure that the machine 2 closing is indeed from your `cron`. Look into its log files, use `pstree`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 
There was another service (third party) which i gave access key to my ec2 instance that open/shut my instance and i forgot about it.
Well, i deleted it back than and so i assumed it wont be active anymore.

Anyhow, the case is solved.

Thank you all.